# Latex. Misplaced Figure

Tags: position, latex, figure

I'm trying to insert an image into the text, but the second one is misplaced and I don't know why because I've wrote the same code than the previous image.

Does anyone can help me with this?

[image]

Comment: You should find your answer here (possible duplicate): [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the image is greater than what is left in the paper. 
You need to do three things if you want to fit it in the same page:

1. substitute line 345 for "\begin{figure}[!h]"
2. substitute line 348 for "\includegraphics[width=XXX\linewidth]{figuras/hl7_hapi_users}" and change the valor of XXX until it fits.
3. write \pagebreak in line 352.

Comment: I think that it is already set as solved, right? Please tell me if not because I'm new here!

Comment: I don't know how to check it. Is just to let the community know it is solved.But it looks like.